# Android Tesseract (Tess-two) OCR Poor results with Seven Segment

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract, google-vision, seven-segment-display

I am working on an app where you take a picture of a device and it stores the information. However, due to the device using seven segment display / LCD i am struggling to get good results.

I have used Firebase OCR, Google Vision ML Kit, And Tesseract (Tess-two).

Each of them are providing poor results, especially Tesseract considering i have trained and fine tuned it to recognise 3 types of seven segment fonts to a 0.09 error rate.

I have also tried using other peoples traineddata, such as [letsgodigital](https://github.com/arturaugusto/display_ocr)

I have converted the image to greyscale and then binarized it, i have also whitelisted only numbers and still can't detect the text properly. What else can i do to improve the results?

Results below are both tesseract.

[image: Tesseract poor results][image]

Comment: I'm sorry but can you give me the code that you use for "converted the image to greyscale and then binarized it"

Answer (score 1):

Tesseract is good at recognizing documents.
The example you gave contains pretty irrelevant information such as the machine and disturbing logo.

Doing the text localization to separate the seven-segment content out would be better a way to preprocess it.